# can you do an ALTER VIEW and an ALTER WHERE

Tags: sql

When you do an

```
ALTER TABLE <name>
```

You can use ALTER COLUMN so you don't have to type out the entire table definition again.

Say I have a view which ends with `WHERE entity = 'MyEntity'`

rather than having to basically write the entire view definition out, can I just do something like...

```
ALTER VIEW schools ALTER WHERE entity = 'newMyEntity'
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which DBMS? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? SQL Server?

Comment: It would really have to run on both Oracle and MS SQL Server

Comment: That's an *exceptionally* narrow use case, for very little benefit. Why would the database providers spend time building this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really can't. The problem is that the system would need to somehow be able to figure out  "correct" sql for your new views based on changes you made to original table (column type etc). While that could work for trivial cases (adding new columns, using simple views, etc), that would be a nearly impossible thing to do in generic case. Also such change would imply the need to review indexes, constrains on the table etc.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge and assuming you are talking of SqlServer you can't do that. 
[Here is the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms173846%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)